# Comparing input time and current time

Tags: excel, vba

How do I check if the input time is less than or equal to the current time in Excel VBA?

Below is my code snippet:

```
time = "11:59:59 AM"
If Format(TimeValue(Now)) <= time Then
    test = "Good morning!"
Else
    test = "Good Afternoon!"
End If
```

This always returns "Good Afternoon!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the to convert a string representing time to an actual time value with [TimeValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz2ahtzs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). It seems your process was a little backwards. You wanted to get a true numerical time value to compare against Now; not a string to compare against a string representing Now.

```
dim tm as date
tm = TimeValue("11:59:59 AM")
If TimeValue(Now) <= tm Then
    test = "Good morning!"
Else
    test = "Good Afternoon!"
End If
```

It's never a good idea to work with a variable that has the same name as a reserved word.

Comment: Hi,it seems that works as seem as what I have done before. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies; I forgot to strip off the Date portion of Now to leave only the Time portion. Rectified above.

Comment: Thank you so much Jeeped for the guidance! It is now working well!